# How can I tell if SQLite is installed properly on Linux?

Tags: linux, sqlite, cpanel, joomla-extensions

I'm using a web hosting service on a shared account. They have MySQL, but I need to use SQLite for a Joomla extension called SobiPro. How can I tell if SQLite is installed and working properly on Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., it is usually compiled directly into the application that uses it.

In your case, SQLite must be enabled in the PHP configuration.
The SobiPro [documentation](http://sobipro.sigsiu.net/sobipro/requirements#note-sqlite) says:

> SQLite can be supported directly via the [SQLite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sqlite.php) extension or through the [PHP Data Objects extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

To check PHP extensions, use [get_loaded_extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) or something like `<?php phpinfo(INFO_MODULES); ?>`.